# Why so many symbolic links?

Tags: c++, opencv, shared-libraries

After installation of Opencv 2.4.9, I found it created many symbolic links in /usr/local/lib. Say, for libopencv_core.so.2.4.9, when I use `ls -l`, it showed

```
...
libopencv_core.so -> libopencv_core.so.2.4
libopencv_core.so.2.4 -> libopencv_core.so.2.4.9
libopencv_core.so.2.4.9
...
```

My question is, since it already put the real shared library libopencv_core.so.2.4.9 in /usr/lcoal/lib, why bother to create a symbolic link to it, and even another symbolic link to that symbolic link?

Is it better to put real shared libraries in some other place and make symbolic links to them in /usr/local/lib?

Comment: Search term: "soname"

Comment: This makes more obvious sense if you have more than one version installed and use applications that need different versions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second libopencv_core.so.2.4 ( alias "soname" )  and third libopencv_core.so.2.4.9 ( alias "real name" ) files are the ones that allows you to update libraries ( in this case OpenCV ) and still support programs that want to use older versions of those libraries.

> $ ldd a.out
>   libopencv_core.so.2.4 => /path/to/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4

Running `ldd`, you can see that executable isn't linked to "real name" library ? **Reason: For handling library upgrades.** Consider two scenarios.

1. Library upgrades with backward compatibility =>  the installer( or `ldconfig` ) could update the existing "soname" link ( e.g. libopencv_core.so.2.4 ) to point to newer "real name" library ( e.g. libopencv_core.so.2.4.10 ) and our older executable's will now load the upgraded  library.
2. Library upgrades without backward compatibility => the installer will create new "soname" link ( for e.g libopencv_core.so.3.0 ) to point to new "realname" library ( for e.g libopencv_world.so.3.0.0 ). Programs built here after, could link to the newer library whereas older programs will continue to load the library pointed by older soname ( libopencv_core.so.2.4 ).

About, the first symbolic link libopencv_core.so ( alias "linker name" )  is **only** for the linker. For flags like `-lopencv_core`, gcc prefixes a `lib` and postfixes a `.so` to the library name and searches. So it expects a file with name libopencv_core.so and so the need for first symbolic link. It is never used during program runtime. Also, if are willing to the give "soname" link as a gcc command line parameter instead of `-lopencv_core`, you will never need this soft link.

Better explained here([1](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html)).

Answer (score 3):

This is a very used procedure on Linux systems because it allows you to change the last version of the .so (.so.2.4.9 in your case) while the applications running only knows they need to link with the first .so .

So all programs are loading the first .so which then , through symbolic links, end up loading the currently installed version.

If it were to go like you proposed (just copy the hard .so), then all programs would just complain that they don't find the proper version (in your case 2.4.9). Maybe in the future you will upgrade your openCV to 2.4.10 and all your programs will stop working.

Some projects Actually enforce linking to certain major or medium version. So for example if you only guarantee your program will work for 2.4 versions, you will link it to .so.2.4 instead of .so .

In the end it just helps allot with compatibility.